# Including header files in middle of a c++ program

Tags: c++, header

Is it possible to include a header file in the middle of the code in a c++ program? I mean i wanted to include a header file "cstdlib" in the middle of a program.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the `#include` preprocessor directive anywhere in your code. However, all it does is that it adds the content of the file you are including instead of the directive. So it would not make sense to `#include` an external library in the middle of a function.